# Ant JUnit task doesn't work in TeamCity

Tags: ant, junit, teamcity

There is part of ant script with junit task:

```
...

<target name="test">
  <mkdir dir="path_to_report_dir">
  <junit fork="true" printsummary="true" showoutput="true" maxmemory="1024M">
    <classpath ... />
    <batchtest todir="path_to_report_dir">
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <fileset ... />
    </batchtest>
  </junit>
</target>

...
```

This script works from Eclipse and from command line. But it doesn't work in TeamCity. The last informative message in TeamCity is:
[mkdir] Created dir: path_to_report_dir
Process exit code: 0

It looks like junit task doesn't work and also it stops performting aff all script. Where is trouble in?

Comment: Could you supply a build log? Is there any error thrown? My immediate suspicion is that the junit jar is missing on the TeamCity build machine

Comment: Last messages of build log is: [mkdir] Created dir: path_to_report_dir; Process exit code: 0. So there is no any errors.

Comment: The "[mkdir]" prefix on the message would indicate the problem is with the mkdir ANT task and not junit.... Possible OS issue, creating the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was in `<fileset>` file list. The TeamCity version of Ant doesn't work with strings like `"/test/"` (this mean [select all files recursively](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)); it only works with strings like `"**/test/*.class"`. The local version of Ant supports both variants.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps.... but here's my standard test target:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile-tests">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="test.path"/>
            <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${test.classes.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${test.reports.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
                <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Build output:

```
test:
    [junit] Running org.demo.AppTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.056 sec
```

**Notes**

- Using Junit 4.10.